# Noexcept for classes that use a stringstream

Tags: c++11, exception, noexcept

I have a class that has a `std::stringstream` member:

```
class Buffer
{
    std::stringstream ss_;
};
```

Its move constructor is

```
Buffer::Buffer(Buffer&& buf)
: ss_(std::move(buf.ss_))
{
}
```

I suspect that the move operation will not throw and the move constructor could be `noexcept` because of this. So my questions are:

1. How do I determine if a function from the STL is declared `noexcept`, for example `std::stringstream::str`?
2. If swapping or moving the `stringstream` was not `noexcept`, could I still declare the `Buffer` members `noexcept` and get a call to `std::unexpected()` if an exception is thrown by the `stringstream`? From what I can find that would be the case.
3. Is there a way around the problem, for example an alternate container that can be written to using the stream operators and that is `noexcept`?
4. If I follow [these](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/using-noexcept) suggestions and just do not use `noexcept`, can I expect the compiler to determine if STL containers can use move or need to do a copy instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use [`noexcept` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept):

   ```
   noexcept(std::declval<std::stringstream>().str())
   ```
2. Yes.
3. Memory and I/O are not unlimited resources. Two strategies readily come to mind to handle resource unavailability: throw an exception or terminate the application.
4. Yes, [defaulted special member functions have implicit `nothrow(true)` exception specification when the conditions are met](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec#Explanation), that is, the corresponding special member functions of the base classes and members must also be `nothrow(true)`.